# How to use MacOS Shark to profile my application?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a XCode project. I can build and debug with it. 
Is it possible for me to use Shark to do profiling of my application (e.g. find out what % of the time spent on what method? How many objects are created and destroyed? Where does each object created?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run Shark on your application to get time profile information; see for example 
[this Apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/tools/shark_optimize.html). dtrace is another option; but has a steeper learning curve.

For more general profiling, like object allocation, you want to use Instruments (which is also part of Apple's developer tools suite).

Comment: The Apple link above is no longer available. I suggest attach the title when post a link.

Comment: Lots of things about Apple's development tools has changed in 4 years, and they've taken down and/or replaced quite a bit of content; putting a title with the link wouldn't change that.